visual basic 16 does not support assigning to or passing byref properties with init only setters
i use visual studio 2022 and a nuget that has classes. when i construct a new object and initialize properties in c#  i dont have problem but in vb when i want to initialize properties it shows error:
visual basic 16 does not support assigning to or passing byref properties with init-only setters
thanks to helps

The reason for this error is that Visual Basic 16.0 does not support the use of init-only properties. It was not until Visual Basic 16.9 that the use of init-only properties was allowed. You can refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/whats-new/#visual-basic-169
